# Pass a filtered list to MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am really new to mvc and I am trying to learn it at the moment

I have an application that holds a users animals. The scaffolding built into MVC auto created this code for me so it would display a list of Animals in my BD

```
return View(db.Animals.);
```

How do i edit this code? or what code will produce the same result but only animals wher etheir species is "Cow". I tried:

```
Animal Animal1 = (from animals in db.Animals
                  where animals.Species == "Cow"
                  select animals).FirstOrDefault();

return View(Animal1);
```

But I get an error saying "The view expects a `IEnumerable<>`". Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are passing single object of Animal class not List, remove FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` gives you first entity in the set. If you want all entites with `Species == "Cow"`, just call `ToList` and pass it to the View:

```
List<Animal> cows = (from animals in db.Animals
                      where animals.Species == "Cow"
                      select animals).ToList();

return View(cows);
```

Otherwise, if you want to display just one entity, you need to create another view typed with `Animal` class (unlike `IEnumerable<Animal>` that you most likely have now).